# SASS: @extend within (nested) pseudo class

Tags: sass

I'd like to generate the content of a `%`-class within a pseudo selector. `@extend` works rather unexpected here. Can someone tell me how I would get the *expected CSS*?

#### My SASS

```
%ext
   &:aaa
     color: red

button
  &:bbb
     @extend %ext  // expected: .button:bbb:aaa
```

#### Actual Generated CSS

```
button:aaa:bbb {
    color: red;
}
```

#### Expected CSS

```
button:bbb:aaa {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly,  "the order doesn't matter for CSS" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: The order doesn't matter for the resulting CSS. 
Therefore: Don't mind.